Get simpleName from factory result
I was using my generic method with Class to pass a type name, since I can't use reified. This made me call my methods using MyModule::class.java I recently found out about type factories using ::MyModule and thought maybe I could use that to get the type name out of instead, because it is shorter than the former method.
Problem is that I don't know how to extract the simpleName from the factory result. I could create an instance factory()::class.simpleName but that seems wasteful.
tl;dr:
i want to refactor from
override fun <T: IMyModule>set(key: String, value: String, type: Class<T>) {
   val settings = type.simpleName;
   ...
}
set("COM", "1", SmModule::class.java);

to
override fun <T: IMyModule>set(key: String, value: String, type: () -> T) {
   val settings = type.returnType.simpleName; // doesn't work
   val settings = type()::class.simpleName; // inefficient
   ...
}
set("COM", "1", ::SmModule); 

// so I don't have to type ::class.java every time i use it

IMO proper convention would to be create a reified extension function overload (which would be invoked by set<SmModule>("COM", "1") and leave your original method intact.

This would be perfect but how do i deal with reified in interfaces? Would have gone the reified way instead

Extension function would be declared outside interfaces body in this case and all it would do is use reified type to obtain a Class and call actual implementation.

If MyModule::class.java is too long for you, how about MyModule::class? The parameter type would be KClass<T>, and you can get the simpleName in the same way.

@Pawel that's the way I went with, I added the interface extensions if you could add the answer I'll accept it.

Instead of altering your existing implementation you can create a "extension function overload" which can be inline and reified without issue:
interface IMyInterface {
   fun <T: IMyModule> set(key: String, value: String, type: Class<T>)
   /* ... */
}

inline fun <reified T : IMyModule> IMyInterface.set(key: String, value: String) = set(key, value, T::class.java)

